# What's going wrong with my migrations on CakePHP 4?

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-4.x

I've applied a couple of minor changes to the database structure for my app, adding new columns to a table called Plots. This is one of the migrations -

```
declare(strict_types=1);

use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class AddGarageToPlots extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('plots');
        $table->addColumn('garage', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->update();
    }
}
```

When I apply the migration it seems to run fine: there are no errors and I can see the new column in the database if I connect directly to it but when I try to access data in the new field in a view using, for example, `<?= $plot->garage ?>` it consistently returns `null` even though I have populated this field via the direct connection.

Is there something else I need to do that I'm missing here or is there some way I can check that the migration has worked properly like a schema file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question by reading slightly further in the documentation - [migrations and deployment](https://book.cakephp.org/migrations/3/en/index.html#migrations-and-deployment).

I needed to run `bin/cake schema_cache clear`